# Create a stored procedure to find out employees who has overtime from timesheet table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, time

I do have this below database. (I am not asking for full code idea would be enough)
[image: Schema Design]

In timesheet table sample data is something like this:
[image: Sample data]

Now here are the conditions :

- Must have to write stored procedure
- Status "IN" represents when he/she entered in the office and "OUT"
  represents when he/she is out from the office or went out of the
  office.
- Every time a person enters or goes out using the
  card and it will enter into the database. So in the same date, there
  could be multiple ins and outs for a single person.
- We need to display employees with over-time after 5 PM.
- Note that, one person can login today and can go out tomorrow or after that.
  In between , he/she also can in and out which will not harm the
  overtime.

Conditions seems silly to me and I could use better schema in the design and solve it very efficiently. However it was asked once in interview exam, and I used SQL server cursor but it doesn't meet all the condition. Can anyone please help understand how to solve this problem.

Here is my solution sample:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_get_over_times] 
@officeHours                    INT = 8
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @emp_id         VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @att_date       Date = NULL;
DECLARE @att_time       SMALLDATETIME = NULL;
DECLARE @status         VARCHAR(4) = NULL;
DECLARE @emp_id_2           VARCHAR(10) = NULL;
DECLARE @att_date_2     DATE = NULL;
DECLARE @status_2           VARCHAR(4) = NULL;
DECLARE @att_time_2     SMALLDATETIME = NULL;

DECLARE @duration       int = NULL;

DECLARE c1 CURSOR READ_ONLY 
        FOR 
        SELECT Emp_id,  Att_Date,Att_time
        FROM dbo.timesheet 
        WHERE STATUS = 'IN'
        GROUP BY Emp_id, Att_Date,Att_time
        OPEN c1
        FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @emp_id,@att_date,@att_time


        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN

                SELECT TOP 1 @emp_id_2 = Emp_id, @att_date_2 = Att_Date,  @att_time_2 = Att_time
                FROM dbo.timesheet 
                WHERE STATUS = 'OUT' AND Emp_id = @emp_id AND Att_Date = @att_date;

                IF(@emp_id_2 IS NOT NULL) BEGIN
                    SET @duration = DATEDIFF(minute,@att_time,@att_time_2);
                    IF(@duration < 0 ) BEGIN
                        SET @duration = @duration * -1;
                    END
                    IF(@duration > @officeHours) BEGIN
                       SELECT @emp_id, (@duration- @officeHours) AS 'OverTime';              
                    END                  
                END    
                SET @emp_id_2 = NULL;
                FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO   @emp_id,@att_date,@att_time
        END

        CLOSE c1
        DEALLOCATE c1
```

END

Comment: You are asking for the complete code!! Well that's against the policy of SO!!!

Comment: No idea would be enough

Comment: But your question title clearly states that you need code not idea!!!

Comment: Sir, @GuruprasadRao modified it. Would you please remove those negative dislikes

Comment: Now that you have added code to show your effort, I removed my downvote!! and FYI it's not dislike!! Efforts are always appreciated!!

Comment: and for an idea! I can say just add one more column called `total_time` and when there is update in `out_time` just calculate the difference between `in_time` and `out_time` and update `total_time` in your table!!

Comment: Sir, not allowed to add any columns

Comment: What would be considered an overtime in your case? I didn't understand your last requirement clearly.

Comment: @Rookie13 thank you for your time. Overtime should be considered if anyone stayed after 5 pm however it is not only based on same date. A person could get in today and left tomorrow. And a person will go in and out multiple times between those time. Seems illogical to me however they asked it.

Comment: Yeah that makes no sense to me either. Is it standard 8 hours work day for employees then? Also, what would be considered normal hours for your scenario?

Comment: @Rookie13 , I actually solved it based on time. But couldn't solve what could happen if they ins and out multiple times in one day.

Comment: For that you could possibly build a timeline, for e.g. clock in and clock out time and then order by date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to clarify a bit if it's ok. Have to scoot soon though but someone should wrap up otherwise I'll pick it up tomorrow.

Initially if you start with a query like this...

```
declare @reportend datetime
set @reportend = '20150422'

SELECT outs.emp_id, 
       outs.att_date, 
       max(ins.att_time) 'In', 
       outs.att_time 'Out', 
       datediff(minute, max(ins.att_time), outs.att_time) 'Mins'
FROM timesheet outs
INNER JOIN timesheet ins
   on outs.emp_id = ins.emp_id
   and ins.att_time < outs.att_time
   and ins.status = 'IN'
WHERE outs.status = 'OUT'
   and outs.att_time between dateadd(day,-1,@reportend) and @reportend
group by outs.emp_id, outs.att_date, outs.att_time
```

You can begin to pair up the IN and OUT events - you could even surround the above with brackets in a FROM clause and SUM the mins by employee.

However, what happens when a certain amount of time has passed and you don't see matching pairs of IN and OUT events? Is this something you would report on seperately / correct in your data so we can assume all pairs are complete?

The above approach would cater for overnight work, assuming you're looking at the previous 24 hours for OUT times.

If someone is currently at work at the time of running the report, are you happy to count that session in the following days summary ie when they log out, or do you need to specify a cutoff period?

You might want to cut their times off at midnight, to count hours for each date where they work overnight too. Please clarify a little.

Comment: They didn't mentioned about data matching so we can leave that part.