# Query displays null result when beyond 00:00 (24:00)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, null

I'm using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio to get data from a call center database, and I have a query to get the login/logout time from agents, but every time that the LOGOUT value is beyond 00:00 (24:00), I get null as a result. Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
   ROW_DATE AS [DATE], LOGID AS [ID], 
   LOGIN AS [Login], LOGOUT AS [Logout], 
   LOGOUTREASON as [Reason]
FROM db_xxxx.DBO.HAGLOG WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE ACD = 2
AND (ROW_DATE BETWEEN '2015-05-05 00:00:00' AND '2015-05-05 23:59:59')
AND LOGID IN (98619)
```

Example: If somebody logged in 06:00 PM and logged out 00:30 AM, I'll get NULL value for LOGOUT.

Extracted Data (05/05 - 13/05):

```
DATE                     ID           Login     Logout      Reason
2015-05-05 00:00:00.000  98619      1430848943  1430860539  0
2015-05-05 00:00:00.000  98619      1430860554  NULL        NULL
2015-05-06 00:00:00.000  98619      1430935439  1430935856  8
2015-05-06 00:00:00.000  98619      1430935868  NULL        NULL
2015-05-07 00:00:00.000  98619      1431022232  NULL        NULL
2015-05-08 00:00:00.000  98619      1431108233  NULL        NULL
2015-05-09 00:00:00.000  98619      1431172858  1431195952  0
2015-05-11 00:00:00.000  98619      1431367328  1431367616  8
2015-05-11 00:00:00.000  98619      1431367977  NULL        NULL
2015-05-12 00:00:00.000  98619      1431453768  1431453982  8
2015-05-12 00:00:00.000  98619      1431453997  NULL        NULL
2015-05-13 00:00:00.000  98619      1431540095  1431540631  8
2015-05-13 00:00:00.000  98619      1431540639  NULL        NULL
```

I divide the login/logout values by 86400 to get the right time in hours format.

Comment: This doesn't seem a problem with your query, it seems more like a bug in the app writing the data (or the agent hasn't logged out) - the `LOGOUT` column seems to be null - a query can't fix this. My guess is a bug, e.g. the app assumes the record to update must be on the same day as the login date.

Comment: Can you add some data for example

Comment: As @StuartLC mentioned, have you checked to see if your api that writes data to your call center database does not have any sort of restrictions on logout date value? That would probably narrow down your issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. If you remove the tool name (which isn't relevant), the title is "query", which communicates nothing about the problem you're having or the question you're asking. SSMS is simply a management tool. Add some sample data and the results you'd like to obtain from that data as well while you're doing so. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't, since the program that we use to extract the data through reports (Avaya CMS) can do it correctly, putting even the correct date when beyond 00:00, that's why I assumed I had to do something with the query to get it working, because I need to automate an Excel sheet with this.

Comment: Could you please provide a few days of punch in/punch out data for a single person? That way we might see the pattern that is being written in SQL

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm new to this, I'll do the changes and add some extracted data.

Comment: Instead of `ROW_DATE BETWEEN '2015-05-05 00:00:00' AND '2015-05-05 23:59:59'` do `ROW_DATE >= '2015-05-05' AND ROW_DATE < '2015-05-06'`

Comment: Still getting NULL, even with more days as you can see...

Comment: Given your example, I think you are looking for all agents that have log IN and log OUT for a given day. For that, I believe you will need to use something like this instead `[Login]>= ROW_DATE AND LOGOUT < ROW_DATE` and filter what date you want on row_date. Also, you seem to have null values in your LOGOUT column, why is that?

Comment: That's the problem, I need to know when they've logged in and when they've logged out, it works well for everyone, the problem is when I have someone working through midnight, the query doesn't seems to understand that it's a log out of the next day and gets NULL as a result.

Comment: Well, first of all, the problem is your query is limiting the records by looking for row_date just for a single day (in this case **2015-05-05**). The second problem is the sample data does not really tell us when the agent clocked out on the next day. If it was clocked out on the next day, the LOGIN field should be null. So, these are a couple of things that you will need to sort out before we can help you on this.

Comment: @NepaliRookie Even if I do this 

`SELECT

ROW_DATE,
LOGID AS [ID],
HAGLOG_ID,
LOGIN AS [Login],
LOGOUT AS [Logout],
LOGOUTREASON as [motivo]

FROM db_CMSAlgarTec.DBO.HAGLOG

WHERE ACD = 2

AND (LOGID= '98619')`

I still get NULL results, does it make any difference?

Comment: @MattLacerda It doesn't. Because there are null values for LOGOUT column in your `dbo.HAGLOG` table. As I mentioned earlier, you would need to find out how you can tell looking at the data when the agent clock out on the following day. Your sample data does not say clearly when the agent clocked OUT, if that makes sense? You cannot have value in LOGIN field if there is a NULL value in LOGOUT field in preceding entry.

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774416/create-a-stored-procedure-to-find-out-employees-who-has-overtime-from-timesheet#comment47680809_29774416

Comment: Guys, I did this: `SELECT

ROW_DATE,
LOGID AS [ID],
HAGLOG_ID,
[LOGIN] AS [Login],
LOGOUT AS [Logout],
LOGOUTREASON as [motivo]

FROM db_xxxx.DBO.HAGLOG

WHERE [LOGIN] is null`

and got no results, any idea??